Xubuntu 23.10 not booting after specific use
I've an old Dell E6410 laptop, Xubuntu 23.10 installed on internal SSD.
I used the machine to install 24.04 on an external drive, the laptop booted off a USB-stick with Xubuntu 24.04 installer.
Everything seemed to work nicely, the external drive now boots 24.04 (on 2014 macmini), but the laptop now won't boot from its internal SSD.
Boot-Repair Summary:
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda2,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 23.10 entry (sda1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-31-generic
Warning: failed to launch javaldx - java may not function correctly
The settings chosen by the user will reinstall the grub-efi of
sda2,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Mount /dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/sda2 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-31-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 efibootmgr -v before grub install
EFI variables are not supported on this system.


chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 uname -r
6.8.0-31-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sda1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 efibootmgr -v after grub install
EFI variables are not supported on this system.

Warning: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr).

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-112-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-112-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

Locked-NVram detected. Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 23.10 entry (sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 23.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 23.10 on sda2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: A07(4.6) from Dell Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled - This system doesn't support Secure Boot.
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0006,0000,0003,0001,0002,0004,0007
Boot0000  Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,,0x0)
      dp: 05 01 09 00 01 00 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
Boot0001* Internal HDD  BBS(HD,,0x0)50303a2043543530304d583530305353443120202020202020202020202000
      dp: 05 01 09 00 02 00 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 50 30 3a 20 43 54 35 30 30 4d 58 35 30 30 53 53 44 31 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 00
Boot0002* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,,0x0)5553422053746f726167652044657669636500
      dp: 05 01 09 00 05 00 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 55 53 42 20 53 74 6f 72 61 67 65 20 44 65 76 69 63 65 00
Boot0003* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(CDROM,,0x0)50313a2054535354636f7270204456442b2f2d52572054532d553633334600
      dp: 05 01 09 00 03 00 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 50 31 3a 20 54 53 53 54 63 6f 72 70 20 44 56 44 2b 2f 2d 52 57 20 54 53 2d 55 36 33 33 46 00
Boot0004  Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,,0x0)49424120474520536c6f74203030433820763133353200
      dp: 05 01 09 00 06 00 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 49 42 41 20 47 45 20 53 6c 6f 74 20 30 30 43 38 20 76 31 33 35 32 00
Boot0006* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,6e44bb34-6c4e-4654-85c0-2963cd78cd1f,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
      dp: 04 01 2a 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 98 21 00 00 00 00 00 34 bb 44 6e 4e 6c 54 46 85 c0 29 63 cd 78 cd 1f 02 02 / 04 04 34 00 5c 00 45 00 46 00 49 00 5c 00 75 00 62 00 75 00 6e 00 74 00 75 00 5c 00 73 00 68 00 69 00 6d 00 78 00 36 00 34 00 2e 00 65 00 66 00 69 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
Boot0007* UEFI: INT13(USB,0x80) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/VenHw(aa7ba38a-dabf-40c3-8d18-b55b39609ef7,8001000000005553422020202020ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)/HD(2,GPT,68f11f7c-9460-4739-8f7b-899a4819eea1,0x792144,0x279c)
      dp: 02 01 0c 00 d0 41 03 0a 00 00 00 00 / 01 01 06 00 00 1d / 01 04 3a 00 8a a3 7b aa bf da c3 40 8d 18 b5 5b 39 60 9e f7 80 01 00 00 00 00 55 53 42 20 20 20 20 20 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff / 04 01 2a 00 02 00 00 00 44 21 79 00 00 00 00 00 9c 27 00 00 00 00 00 00 7c 1f f1 68 60 94 39 47 8f 7b 89 9a 48 19 ee a1 02 02 / 7f ff 04 00

64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/BOOT/bootx64.efi
925029921cfc9e40f54f55d4cffbdd49   sda1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
857e495f63f23c842e2b074e692b6e3a   sda1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
1d99ff510dac8535d215797ad5e69230   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
857e495f63f23c842e2b074e692b6e3a   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: F236DF86-1EDF-400D-A72D-17282CDC8963
       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
sda2  1050624 976771071 975720448 465.3G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 28.65 GiB, 30765219840 bytes, 60088320 sectors
Disk identifier: 68F11F7C-9460-4739-8F79-899A4819EEA1
       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       64  7938371  7938308  3.8G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  7938372  7948511    10140    5M EFI System
sdb3  7948512  7949111      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  7950336 60086271 52135936 24.9G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:500GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA CT500MX500SSD1:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:500GB:500GB:ext4::;
sdb:30.8GB:scsi:512:512:gpt: USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1:;
1:32.8kB:4064MB:4064MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:4064MB:4070MB:5192kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:4070MB:4070MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:4071MB:30.8GB:26.7GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                   PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                               
├─sda1 vfat     ADF4-AC72                            d6b9d819-3823-474b-a3aa-b0c2993d0e3b                         EFI System Partition
└─sda2 ext4     a09c8df2-7b99-4d7c-99c9-052ccac810ef 844376d0-b14a-4c4a-bb6c-38ab0eafb739                         
sdb    iso9660  2024-04-24-20-17-44-00                                                    Xubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2024-04-24-20-17-44-00               68f11f7c-9460-4739-8f78-899a4819eea1 Xubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2 vfat     37B6-BC6E                            68f11f7c-9460-4739-8f7b-899a4819eea1 ESP                     Appended2
├─sdb3                                               68f11f7c-9460-4739-8f7a-899a4819eea1                         Gap1
└─sdb4 ext4     8da390ef-5062-46cb-8b70-e940f17bee11 d2db3801-df32-40b2-ae72-2e9d1a0ad733 writable                

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                                       504M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2                                                     394.9G   8% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs                                                       49.3K  15% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1                                                     vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda2                                                     ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid a09c8df2-7b99-4d7c-99c9-052ccac810ef root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   a09c8df2-7b99-4d7c-99c9-052ccac810ef
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=a09c8df2-7b99-4d7c-99c9-052ccac810ef /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=ADF4-AC72  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 186.016597748 = 199.733800960  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  30.813472748 = 33.085714432   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-112-generic                2
 186.016597748 = 199.733800960  boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic                  2
  30.813472748 = 33.085714432   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
  85.750972748 = 92.074405888   boot/initrd.img                                2
 171.242656708 = 183.870402560  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-112-generic             6
  85.750972748 = 92.074405888   boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-41-generic               2
 171.242656708 = 183.870402560  boot/initrd.img.old                            6

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18228 Oct  2  2023 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Oct  2  2023 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14459 Oct  2  2023 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Oct  2  2023 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Oct  2  2023 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Oct  2  2023 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Sep  6  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jul 31  2020 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2SzPq8Tz2Y/
My process:
Power button, tapped F12, at F12 screen, under UEFI Boot: I chose 'UEFI: ...USB', Not 'Ubuntu'
Machine booted off the USB-stick, at Grub I chose 'Try or Install'.
At desktop, I turned on external drive (WD-1T). Waited a minute.
Fired up the installer. Early on the installer asked to update, I did this. Chose Interactive Installation, then Xubuntu Desktop, Install 3rd party stuff, Erase Disc and Install, Somewhere in there I chose 'WD-1T' as install location, filled out the account info asked for and began the install.
At the end of install I chose 'continue', found nothing to see, quit the installer, turned off machine. Tested WD-1T which booted 24.04 no problem.
I booted the laptop, tapped F12, chose 'UEFI Boot: Ubuntu'. No Luck. Tried again, at F12 chose 'Legacy boot: Internal HD'. No luck.
Booted from USB-stick again, got out Terminal and did:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
Chose the 'Recommended Repair' as that's worked for me with this machine in the past. No luck. I tried the same again, no luck.
I can't imagine what happened during that install process. Why would the installer, etc. disturb the internal drive?

Thoughts? How about the boot repair log?

Exact steps used to do the 24.04 install? Please edit the question and add this info.

Boot-repair log and install process added to question. Thanks.

Yesterday; ran boot-repair (USBstick 24.04) again, this time purged GRUB. No luck. Hardware issues?
Today I extracted the SSD (23.10) from the laptop, it boots up fine on macmini.
I installed HDD (UbuntuStudio 24.04) into laptop. Wouldn't boot via UEFI, did boot under Legacy.
Drive and motherboard seem OK.
Next; I'll boot USBstick -23.10-, try boot-repair again, see if having the same OS version as internal drive will make the difference.

admission of guilt—mac user...
I went to the BIOS, to UEFI boot sequence, hit 'Load Defaults'. That wiped out all related boot sequences. Clicked 'Add Boot Sequence'. That new sequence was all filled out, so I named it and 'Applied'.
Re-booted machine—success, booted internal 23.10 drive like nothing was wrong. Relief.

Just to make sure you know that support for 23.10 ends very soon and you may want to upgrade. It is more complex to upgrade once a release has gone EOL. Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) reaches End of Life on July 11, 2024.
